# Build a Simple HTTPServer inside Docker image with Python

Tags: python, docker, port, simplehttpserver

I have a docker image running, but I have no access to management since they are given to us  by an administrator.

I want to run a simple HTTP-Server from a Python script. The script is the following:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer as socketserver
import os
import threading

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    path_to_image = 'RGBWebcam1.png'
    img = open(path_to_image, 'rb')
    statinfo = os.stat(path_to_image)
    img_size = statinfo.st_size
    print(img_size)

def do_HEAD(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "image/png")
    self.send_header("Content-length", img_size)
    self.end_headers()

def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "image/png")
    self.send_header("Content-length", img_size)
    self.end_headers() 
    f = open(path_to_image, 'rb')
    self.wfile.write(f.read())
    f.close()         

class MyServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_adress, RequestHandlerClass):
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        socketserver.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_adress, RequestHandlerClass, False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "172.17.0.2", 9999
    server = MyServer((HOST, PORT), MyHandler)
    server.server_bind()
    server.server_activate()
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.start()
    while(1):
        print "test"
```

I looked up the IP-Adress with `ifconfig` however it is a different adress like the one I use when connecting to the Docker Image (it is a 141.19 ... address). So now if I try to reach the page it is not available on neither one of the adresses. Is there any way to route it to the 'real' IP-Address ?

Comment: That's a local network IP you're binding it to - just to check, are you on the local when you're trying to access that port? Are you aware of any firewall policies that might prevent you?

Comment: Yes it is our companies local network IP domain, I do not know about the Servers firewall policies